# Custom Python Remove Interpreter with OpenVINO initialization

Tags: python, openvino

I use PyCharm to connect to a remote interpreter (but I guess the answer is somewhat unrelated): basically, PyCharm connects to a remote Python interpreter through SSH and execute the code on a remote machine.

The remote interpreter that I used is actually "tweaked". It is a file called `mypython` that contains the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash -l
export PATH="/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/usr/local/cuda-11.1/bin:/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:${PATH}"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/ubuntu/.local/lib:/usr/local/cuda-11.1/lib64:/home/ubuntu/.local/lib:/usr/local/cuda-11.1/lib64:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
export PYTHONPATH="/home/ubuntu/VideoProcessingFramework/install/bin:${PYTHONPATH}"
export PATH="/home/ubuntu/FFmpeg/build_x64_release_shared/bin:${PATH}"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/ubuntu/VideoProcessingFramework/install/bin:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/ubuntu/FFmpeg/build_x64_release_shared/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"

export PATH="/home/ubuntu/pytorch/build/bin:${PATH}"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/ubuntu/pytorch/build/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"

# My attempt at having OpenVINO working on PyCharm remote interpreter
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/opt/intel/openvino_2021.1.110/python/python3.6:/opt/intel/openvino_2021.1.110/python/python3:/opt/intel/openvino_2021.1.110/deployment_tools/tools/post_training_optimization_toolkit:/opt/intel/openvino_2021.1.110/deployment_tools/open_model_zoo/tools/accuracy_checker:/opt/intel/openvino_2021.1.110/deployment_tools/model_optimizer:/opt/intel/openvino_2021.1.110/data_processing/dl_streamer/python:/opt/intel/openvino_2021.1.110/data_processing/gstreamer/lib/python3.6/site-packages:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages"
export OpenCV_DIR="/opt/intel/openvino_2021.1.110/opencv/cmake"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/opt/intel/openvino_2021.1.110/data_processing/dl_streamer/lib:/opt/intel/openvino_2021.1.110/data_processing/gstreamer/lib:/opt/intel/openvino_2021.1.110/opencv/lib:/opt/intel/openvino_2021.1.110/deployment_tools/ngraph/lib:/opt/intel/openvino_2021.1.110/deployment_tools/inference_engine/external/hddl_unite/lib:/opt/intel/openvino_2021.1.110/deployment_tools/inference_engine/external/hddl/lib:/opt/intel/openvino_2021.1.110/deployment_tools/inference_engine/external/gna/lib:/opt/intel/openvino_2021.1.110/deployment_tools/inference_engine/external/mkltiny_lnx/lib:/opt/intel/openvino_2021.1.110/deployment_tools/inference_engine/external/tbb/lib:/opt/intel/openvino_2021.1.110/deployment_tools/inference_engine/lib/intel64"
export GST_SAMPLES_DIR="/opt/intel/openvino_2021.1.110/data_processing/dl_streamer/samples"
export MODELS_PATH="/root/intel/dl_streamer/models"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/intel/openvino_2021.1.110/data_processing/dl_streamer/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/intel/openvino_2021.1.110/data_processing/gstreamer/lib/pkgconfig:"
export GSTREAMER_EXECUTABLES_DIR="/opt/intel/openvino_2021.1.110/data_processing/gstreamer/bin:/opt/intel/openvino_2021.1.110/data_processing/gstreamer/bin/gstreamer-1.0"
export GST_PLUGIN_PATH="$GST_PLUGIN_PATH:/opt/intel/openvino_2021.1.110/data_processing/gstreamer/lib/gstreamer-1.0"
export GST_PLUGIN_SCANNER="/opt/intel/openvino_2021.1.110/data_processing/gstreamer/bin/gstreamer-1.0/gst-plugin-scanner"
export GST_VAAPI_ALL_DRIVERS=1


/usr/bin/python3 "$@"
```

This allows me to specify some environment variables required by Python. Since I install OpenVINO on the remote machine, I would need to add to `mypython` code the command: `source /opt/intel/openvino_2021.1.110/bin/setupvars.sh`  . However, once I do this, it seems that PyCharm refuses to use my `mypython` interpreter (it just gets stuck).

Motivation:

- If I ssh into my remote machine and run `source /opt/intel/openvino_2021.1.110/bin/setupvars.sh` I can then import cv2 correctly from python3
- From the PyCharm remote interpreter instead I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2882, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-c8ec22b3e787>", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: /opt/intel/openvino_2021.1.110/opencv/lib/libopencv_dnn.so.4.5: undefined symbol: _ZN15InferenceEngine10CNNNetworkC1ERKSt10shared_ptrIN6ngraph8FunctionEE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution:

- log into the server using ssh
- run `source /opt/intel/openvino_2021.1.110/bin/setupvars.sh`
- run `printenv`
  Include all the variables into the `mypython` source code.
  I would still like to know if there is a way to  run `source /opt/intel/openvino_2021.1.110/bin/setupvars.sh` within  `mypython` source code.

EDIT: in my case*removing* this from my environment variables fixed the issue:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/ubuntu/.local/lib:/usr/local/cuda-11.1/lib64:/home/ubuntu/.local/lib:/usr/local/cuda-11.1/lib64:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
```

Not sure if I had an old OpenCV version compiled with cuda.